# User uploading logo with no transparency

Tags: registration, customisation, user-generated-content, upload, uploading-documents

I am currently designing a registration journey where non tech-savvy users can build their own website.

In one of the steps, users will have to upload their logo that will be displayed in the top-left corner of both their customer facing website (above a full screen image) and in their dashboard (on a white nav bar).

Target users will have their own brand/logo, but are likely to not be acquainted with the idea of file types (JPEG, PNG, SVG) and transparent background, the latter being the ideal choice -the logo will be placed on an image.

[image]

The visual design cannot be changed.

There is the possibility that people will upload JPEGs with visible background. This doesn't present a usability issue, but definitely ruins the overall experience and does not produce a "professional" output.

Websites like WIX don't even deal with the problem ("Upload a PNG", they say).

What are best practice in a scenario like this?
1) allowing them to upload any type of logo, and slightly ruining the overall result? (bare in mind, this will be their website, and guaranteeing them a professional output is a fundamental part of the experience)
2) recommending to upload a PNG; if not possible, advising them to skip and later, after getting their hands on a PNG or SVG, uploading it? (this would break the flow)
3) Other solution?

Comment: Can you realistically define "professional output" in a way that most of your users will fully understand? With a photo background there is no way of guaranteeing that the user won't upload an image and a logo that are similar in colour making the logo effectively disappear - is that going to give a "professional output"? By all means make recommendations but remember that you're dealing with UGC and all the unexpectedness that it brings.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to define what the user should do?
What if i want to have my logo displayed on a white (or any other color) background?

Stop forcing your aesthetic perceptions onto the user and allow them to upload whatever they want as their logo.

**What you can do is educate the user about the option to upload a logo with a transparent background and guide them.**

Comment: You're right about not imposing any aesthetic direction to users (they won't be blocked if they want to upload a JPG)

It's true that some of them will want to upload a bounded logo, but in that  case, the logo will be probably designed within a shape from the beginning.

The reason behind my question is that a logo is usually designed to be floating, not limited by a background; the white/black bounding box produced by a JPEG is not part of the logo itself, and users could not understand why they would get the background in the final product.

Comment: I agree with @Pectoralis Major, especially since some brands require there to always be a background with a certain colour behind the logo. The easy.com brand for example. You can include the instruction that transparent logos are possible in the upload flow.